# How can i put navigationbar after a splash screen?

Tags: iphone

I an new in iphone application i want to put Nevigation controller after a splash screen so how can i put?Is there any way to put nevigationbar in my application without Splash Screen.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to get a splash screen* is to use Default.png - this is the image that the iPhone puts on the screen while your app starts up - see [the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/Tools/#GENERAL-CREATE_THE_IMAGE_THAT_APPEARS_IN_MY_APPLICATION_S_WINDOW_ON_LAUNCH) for more information.

And to get a basic navigation controller application running, the easiest way to see this is to make a new project - in Xcode choose File->New Project and then choose a Navigation Based Application - this will make a new project that has an empty Navigation Controller.

If you want to get the splash screen to stay on for longer, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901410/adding-logo-for-iphone-app/1902873#1902873)

Hope that helps,

Sam

*Actually, the apple docs want you not to make a splash screen but to make a screenshot of the first page of your app so it appears to load faster - very few people do this, most make a splash screen and apple don't seem to mind too much.